# I keep getting NaN and then number in React.. how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vSdz.png)

```
const number = parseInt(props.detail.price,10)
        const toLocale = number.toLocaleString("ko-KR")
        
       

        console.log(toLocale)
    return (
        <div>
            <Descriptions title="상품정보" bordered>
                <Descriptions.Item label="가격">{toLocale} 원</Descriptions.Item>
                <Descriptions.Item label="판매수">{props.detail.sold}</Descriptions.Item>
                <Descriptions.Item label="열람수">{props.detail.views}</Descriptions.Item>
                <Descriptions.Item label="상품설명" span={2}>{props.detail.description} </Descriptions.Item>
            </Descriptions>  

 

      


**//I sent my props from here** 

    function Page(props) {    
        const productId = props.match.params.productId
        
        const [Product, setProduct] = useState({})
    
        
        
        useEffect(() => {
            axios.get(`/api/product/products_by_id?id=${productId}&type=single`)
            .then(response =>{
                setProduct(response.data[0])
               
            })
            .catch(err=> alert(err))
        }, [])    
    
        return (
            <div style={{width:'100%', padding: '3rem 4rem'}}>
                <div style={{display:'flex', justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center', paddingBottom:'40px'}}>
                     <h1 style={{fontWeight:900}}>{Product.title}</h1> 
                </div>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
    
                    <Row gutter={[16,16]}>
    
                        <Col sm={24} lg={12} ><ProductImage detail={Product}/></Col>
                        <Col sm={24} lg={12}><ProductInfo detail={Product}/></Col>
                    </Row>
                    
    
                </div>
            
            
        )
    }
    
    export default Page
```

The price keeps showing NaN and then number.. I tried to use replace() but it doesn't work. I console Product from useState and it returns an empty obeject and the proeject object.. how can this happen ?

what should I do to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `detail` is `undefined` until your Axios request comes back. This causes `number` to be `NaN` because `parseInt(undefined)` is `NaN`

You should implement some kind of loading state in the `Page` component. The most basic example would be to render `null` while loading.

I would recommend changing the initial state of `Product` to be `undefined` instead of `{}`. Then you can determine if your request is loading based on whether `Product` is `undefined`. If it is loading you can simply return `null` (or a loading spinner, for example).

Here's what that might look like:

```
function Page(props) {    
    const productId = props.match.params.productId
    
    // Notice: initial state is undefined, instead of `{}`
    const [Product, setProduct] = useState()

    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`/api/product/products_by_id?id=${productId}&type=single`)
        .then(response =>{
            setProduct(response.data[0])
            
        })
        .catch(err=> alert(err))
    }, [])

    // While request is loading, return null
    // Alternatively, you can render some kind of loading state like a spinner or blank table
    if (!Product) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
        <div style={{width:'100%', padding: '3rem 4rem'}}>
            <div style={{display:'flex', justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center', paddingBottom:'40px'}}>
                  <h1 style={{fontWeight:900}}>{Product.title}</h1> 
            </div>
                <br/>
                <br/>

                <Row gutter={[16,16]}>

                    <Col sm={24} lg={12} ><ProductImage detail={Product}/></Col>
                    <Col sm={24} lg={12}><ProductInfo detail={Product}/></Col>
                </Row>
                

            </div>
        
        
    )
}
```

Comment: I added extra code where it contains props.

Comment: @Cdoggo I've updated my answer based on your edit

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works perfectly ! I've been searching what could be wrong but you really saved my day !!

Answer (score 0):

Can you console log props & share the object we can find the exact reason for returning the NaN value. parseInt('non-number',10) will return the NaN value.

You can refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt this link for more details.

Answer (score 0):

according to my knowledge its the issue of rendering lately.
Do that {props?.detail?.sold} or {props?.detail?.views}

Put question mark(?) Before accessing element in the object. It ensures that variable should render after getting the object..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).